# Hibernate respond on Post-mapping method with Spring boot returning null after sending request to MySQL database

Tags: spring, boot

After ruining the programming, using Postman for client testing with the Api, from  the  controller, the response data keep returning Null Null

everything seems fine with the code  no  error messages  or  prompt ,  but  Hibernate keep returning  null  null and  no  data which  post is inserted in the MySQL database (code below ,please  help)

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "student_lib")
public class StudentLibrary {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String addressess;
    private String email;
    
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddressess() {
        return addressess;
    }
    public void setAddressess(String addressess) {
        this.addressess = addressess;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    public StudentLibrary(Long id, String name, String addressess, String email) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.addressess = addressess;
        this.email = email;
    }
```

Service

```
@Service
public class LibService {

    
    @Autowired
    
    private LibRepository repository;
    
    public StudentLibrary getLibraryById(Long id) {
        
    return repository.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    public StudentLibrary insertLibrary(StudentLibrary studentLibrary) {
        
        return repository.save(studentLibrary);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Api")
public class LibController {
    @Autowired 
    LibService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/Lib")
    
    public StudentLibrary getAllDataById(Long id) {
        
        return service.getLibraryById(id);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public StudentLibrary insertData(StudentLibrary studentLibrary) {
        
        return service.insertLibrary(studentLibrary);
    }

}
```

outcome respond  with  postman

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "name": null,
    "addressess": null,
    "email": null
}
```

Comment: Stop using entities in the API. Learn about 3tier architecture

Comment: How do you call the service, iare the data stored in the db?

Comment: no sir the  data are  not stored in DB sir , it  return null

Answer (score 2):

You are missing [@RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux/controller/ann-methods/requestbody.html) annotation before the StudentLibrary parameter of your POST api, otherwise it will be taken by HTTP body.

About the GET one, if that Long id is passed through URL, you should use [@PathVariable("id")](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) and modify the url as @GetMapping("/Lib/{id}") (brackets included)